# How to get count in MySql with multiple condition

Tags: mysql, database, date, count, pivot

I have a schema in following structure.

Test_Table:

```
ID        Date                     measurement
IT-1      2019-01-01 13:12:11      50
IT-2      2019-01-02 15:10:24      75
IT-3      2019-01-03 17:19:18      100
IT-4      2019-02-02 08:17:09      25
IT-5      2019-02-04 09:13:07      150
IT-6      2019-02-05 11:10:09      98
```

Using the `Test_Table`, I want to derive the output in the following format in MySql.

I need to put the condition on `measurement` column, if the value in that column is less than or equal to 50 than show the count in different column in the output. Where the Month can be derived from the Date column of Test_Table.

I have tried to use the case when condition, but couldn't get the desired output yet.

Example:

```
Month       Total_ID      <=50       50-100     100-200
Jan-2019       3            1          2          0
Feb-2019       3            1          1          1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b-%Y') As "Month",
    COUNT(*) Total_ID,
    SUM(measurement <= 50) AS "<= 50",
    SUM(measurement > 50 AND measurement <= 100) AS "50-100",
    SUM(measurement > 100 AND measurement <= 200) AS "100-200"
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b-%Y')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wY47DJKh734dqLiP6VrFcq/4)**:

```
| Month    | Total_ID | <= 50 | 50-100 | 100-200 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- | ------ | ------- |
| Jan-2019 | 3        | 1     | 2      | 0       |
| Feb-2019 | 3        | 1     | 1      | 1       |
```

Comment: Thanks :) How can I add addition column of sum based on the criteria (i.e For `Jan-2019` month the sum for `50-100` would be 150).